# Run jetbrains hub in a subdomain in a subfolder with apache

Tags: apache-2.4, hub

I am using jetbrains tools to manage a team. using apache to manage my domains/subdomains. have a sub domain named `dev.sepidarr.ir` which is responsible as the main entry point of my development environment.

**dev.sepidarr.ir.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /home/neacodin/domains/dev.sepidarr.ir/
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  <Directory "/home/neacodin/domains/dev.sepidarr.ir">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ServerName dev.sepidarr.ir
  ServerAlias www.dev.sepidarr.ir

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.dev.sepidarr.ir [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dev.sepidarr.ir
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

I want to have each jetbrains' tools running in a different url, for example I need upsource to run as `dev.sepidarr.ir/upsource` and hub in `dev.sepidarr.ir/hub`.

Based on the official [jetbrains tutorial about how to setup a reverse proxy server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Proxy-Configuration.html), I have created a `.conf` file for hub as follow.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName dev.sepidarr.ir

  DefaultType none

  RewriteEngine on
  AllowEncodedSlashes on

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
  RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:8110/$1 [P]

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /hub/ http://localhost:8110/hub
  ProxyPassReverse /hub/ http://localhost:8110/hub

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I navigate to `dev.sepidarr.ir` it works fine. But when I try to open `dev.sepidarr.ir/hub` I get `404 Not Found`.

I have also configured hub to run with a custom base-url with the following command.

```
./hub.sh configure--listen-port 8110 --base-url https://dev.sepidarr.ir/hub
```

But nothing changed.